# Is it possible to ORDER BY <column number> from SELECT list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table `User` with `Name` and `Address`. If I want to `ORDER BY` `Address`, I will then do the following :

```
SELECT UserID, Name, Address FROM User ORDER BY Address ASC
```

Or this if I want to `ORDER BY` `Name` :

```
SELECT UserID, Name, Address FROM User ORDER BY Name ASC
```

But is it possible if I want to order based on column number? I was thinking of something like this :

```
SELECT UserID, Name, Address FROM User ORDER BY (0) ASC --ORDER BY UserID
SELECT UserID, Name, Address FROM User ORDER BY (1) ASC --ORDER BY Name
SELECT UserID, Name, Address FROM User ORDER BY (2) ASC --ORDER BY Address
```

Comment: You just have to try it to figure it out.

Comment: @X.L.Ant: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Just run one of your sample queries and see if it works.

Comment: @X.L.Ant: note to self - always try to run the code even if it sounds stupid before posting :) thanks!

Comment: It's usually best avoided. You should try, as much as possible, to write SQL (and code that interfaces with SQL) using column *names* and not make any dependencies or assumptions on the order in which columns appear in a result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without the brackets like this:

```
SELECT UserID, Name, Address FROM User ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

It doesn't generally seem to be a recommended approach though

[sql-server-order-by-columnname-vs-order-by-columnnumber](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/27/sql-server-order-by-columnname-vs-order-by-columnnumber/)